# Chaning a Variable in Main from 2nd activity

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to change a variable called `DevMessage` (in MainActiviy) from a second activity. But I don't want to close the 2nd activity after I changed it.
Everything I find is how to get a variable from one activity to another but without chaning it in the Mainactivity.

Any ideas that can solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare `DevMessage` variable as `public static`.
Then from second activity change it like below

```
Activity1.DevMessage = whatever.....
```